# bash zip error: Invalid command arguments (short option '\' not supported)

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, zip

hi guys i have a problem with this code:

```
for dir in ~/Documents/CMDsh/*/     # list directories in the form "/tmp/dirname/"
do
    countFolder=$((countFolder+1));
    #echo $dir; #res: /home/arutosio/Documents/CMDsh/20060 Little Non - Hanamaru Sensation (TV Size)/
    dir=${dir%*/};#remove the trailing "/" #res: /home/arutosio/Documents/CMDsh/20060 Little Non - Hanamaru Sensation (TV Size)
    nameFolder=${dir##*/}; #print everything after the final "/" #res: 20060 Little Non - Hanamaru Sensation (TV Size)
    pathNameFolder="$(echo $nameFolder | sed 's/ /\\ /g')"; #res: 20060\ Little\ Non\ -\ Hanamaru\ Sensation\ (TV\ Size)
    pathNameFolder="$(echo $pathNameFolder | sed 's/(/\\(/g')"; #res: 20060\ Little\ Non\ -\ Hanamaru\ Sensation\ \(TV\ Size)
    pathNameFolder="$(echo $pathNameFolder | sed 's/)/\\)/g')"; #res: 20060\ Little\ Non\ -\ Hanamaru\ Sensation\ \(TV\ Size\)
    echo "NumFolder: $countFolder  Creating... \"$nameFolder.osz\"";    # print everything after the final "/"
    echo "zip -r -j -9 ~/osuLazerBeatmap/$pathNameFolder.zip $pathNameFolder/*"; #res: >
    #zip -r -j -9 ~/osuLazerBeatmap/20060\ Little\ Non\ -\ Hanamaru\ Sensation\ \(TV\ Size\).zip 20060\ Little\ Non\ -\ Hanamaru\ Sensation\ \(TV\ Size\)/*
    zip -r -j -9 ~/osuLazerBeatmap/$pathNameFolder.zip $pathNameFolder/*;
    echo '------------------------------';
done
```

but when i run my sh this line:

```
zip -r -j -9 ~/osuLazerBeatmap/$pathNameFolder.zip $pathNameFolder/*;
```

make this error:
zip error: Invalid command arguments (short option '\' not supported)
i tried to run a the result of this line in my terminal and it is working:
zip -r -j -9 ~/osuLazerBeatmap/20060\ Little\ Non\ -\ Hanamaru\ Sensation\ (TV\ Size).zip 20060\ Little\ Non\ -\ Hanamaru\ Sensation\ (TV\ Size)/*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
for dir in ~/Documents/CMDsh/*/
do
    countFolder=$((countFolder+1))
    dir=${dir%*/}
    nameFolder=${dir##*/}
    zip -r -j -9 ~/osuLazerBeatmap/"$nameFolder".zip "$dir"/*
    echo '------------------------------';
done
```

Notes:

1. Always put references to shell variables in double-quotes.   In this case, that meant replacing:

   ```
   zip -r -j -9 ~/osuLazerBeatmap/$nameFolder.zip $dir/*
   ```

   with

   ```
   zip -r -j -9 ~/osuLazerBeatmap/"$nameFolder".zip "$dir"/*
   ```

   This eliminates the need to attempt escaping with those three lines of sed code.

   The only exception to this rule is when you explicitly want *word splitting* or *pathname expansion*.
2. An example may help.  Let's consider a simple example with a directory with one file:

   ```
   $ ls
   Sensation (TV Size)
   ```

   Let's create a shell variable:

   ```
   $ f='Sensation (TV Size)'
   ```

   Now, let's try using the shell variable unquoted:

   ```
   $ ls $f
   ls: cannot access 'Sensation': No such file or directory
   ls: cannot access '(TV': No such file or directory
   ls: cannot access 'Size)': No such file or directory
   ```

   Notice how much better it works when the shell variable is quoted:

   ```
   $ ls "$f"
   Sensation (TV Size)
   ```

   By quoting the shell variable, no escaping is needed.
3. The shell treats the end of the line as the end of the command.  Thus, while semicolons at the end of a line don't hurt, they are unnecessary.

Comment: nice amazing thank you dude